# How to navigate to the next Material page after getting Successful API response using Multipart request as Http body parameter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I believe `response.statusCode == 200` from my Api because its printing `Uploaded!` How can I store my API response in a variable `(Lets say "jsonResponse")` so that I can pass it to my new MaterialPage `DieticianAfterDateSelectPage`?

**The Error:**

```
    The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("Status")
The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:19
```

//

```
      Future<void> SaveCustomTestBooking() async {


var jsonResponse;
if (EncUserId.isNotEmpty) {
   var postUri = Uri.parse("http://mkklklklklktBooking");
  var request  = http.MultipartRequest('POST',postUri);
  request.fields['VisitDate'] = '_selectedDate';
  request.fields['EncUserId'] = 'EncUserId';

    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    "UserFile", File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync(),
    filename:"Image.jpg",
    contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));

   request.send().then((response){
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {

       print("Uploaded!"); //From here.............
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DieticianAfterDateSelectPage(rresponse:DieticianEncBookingIdModel.fromJson(jsonResponse),)));
       
   } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Somthing went wrong")));
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");

   }
   }


   );}
```

My variable `image` contain my gallery image after method call.

```
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  File? image;
  var fileContent;
  var fileContentBase64;
```

Function to get image from gallery

```
    void filePicker() async {
final File? selectedImage =
    await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
print(selectedImage!.path);
setState(() {
  image = selectedImage;
  
   fileContent = image!.readAsBytesSync();
   fileContentBase64 = base64.encode(fileContent); 
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear how to help. I can see that you are passing a value to `DieticianAfterDateSelectPage`, and your error message.  But you are asking how to store the value in a variable!

What you probably need is to understand the error message. You are getting it because you are calling the `[]` operator on null. You need to check how that's happening, and check the line number 19 in your main.dart as in the error message.

Comment: Ok, Think I didn't explain properly.. What I'm trying to do is I want to first print the response body from api in my console  for that I'm doing `jsonResponse = request.send().then((response){.....`  then pass this to my `DieticianAfterDateSelectPage`  Do you think I properly print this response in my console ? this way-->`jsonResponse =request.send().then((response){.......`

Comment: Because its printing  `Uploaded!` then
`Instance of 'Future<Null>` in my console

Comment: just above `if (response.statusCode == 200) {` you can print the `body` like `print(resposne.body);`

Comment: But you must learn how to use `async` `await` it's a lot more coherent then using `then` Look up terms like promises and futures in dart and javascript

Comment: can I not to store the response in variable this way--> `jsonResponse =request.send().then((response){.......` ?  then printing it like `print(jsonResponse);`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I print my Multipart request body

```
   Future<void> SaveCustomTestBooking() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (EncUserId.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = http.MultipartRequest('POST',Uri.parse("http://myApiTestBooking"));

  response.fields['VisitDate'] = _selectedDate;
  response.fields['EncUserId'] = EncUserId;
  response.fields['Description'] = testTextController.text;

  response.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    "UserFile", File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync(),
    filename:"Image.jpg",
    contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));



  response.send().then((response) async {
  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    isApiCallProcess = false;
    final respBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();// this is how we print body for Multipart request
     jsonResponse = json.decode(respBody.toString());
    print(respBody);
    print("Uploaded!");

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Booked"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF00b3a4),
          ));

       //  Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) =>new MyTestReqDetailsPage(),));
         Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) =>new Home2(),));

  } 
});


}
}
```